# Scheme - Wordtranslator

Tags: scheme, racket

I had to do a word translator in the school, ive tried it like this in the Programm: DrRacket, but when I translate german into english, it gives me "Error", my teacher also don't knows how to fix the mistake, I hope someone of you can help me.

```
(define *lex*
  '((cat Katze)
     (dog Hund)
     (eats frisst)
     (jumps springt)
     (the die)
     (the der)))


(define (wordtranslator word *lex*)
          (cond ((null? liste) 'Error)
                ((not (equal? word (or (car (car list)) (car (cdr (car list)))))) (wordtranslator word (cdr liste)))
                (else
                 (cond
                   ((equal? word (car (car list))) (car (cdr (car list))))
                   ((equal? word (car (cdr (car list)))) (car (car list)))))))
```

when I want to translate "Hund" it shows:

```
> (wordtranslator 'Hund *lex*)
Error
>
```

Comment: `(null? liste)` will be true because `liste` has not been assigned a value. Also later calls such as `(car list)` are problematic because `list` is a built in Racket/scheme function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is unnecessarily complex, and it has a couple of syntax errors - for instance: is the list parameter called `*lex*`, `list` or `liste`? and why nest `cond` expressions, if a single multi-part `cond` suffices? also notice that the way you're using `or` within `equal?` is wrong. It'd be better to try again from scratch:

```
(define (wordtranslator word liste)
        ; if the list is empty, we didn't find the word, signal an error
  (cond ((null? liste) 'Error) 
        ; is the word in the first element of pair?
        ((equal? word (caar liste))
        ; then return the second element of pair
         (cadar liste))
        ; is the word in the second element of pair?
        ((equal? word (cadar liste))
        ; then return the first element of pair
         (caar liste))
        ; otherwise, the word is not in the current pair
        (else
        ; advance the recursion to the next pair
         (wordtranslator word (cdr liste)))))
```

From the comments I understand that you were trying to find first if the word is *not* in the current pair. This is also possible, but IMHO the code will be less readable and you'll need to use more comparisons; also take notice of the correct way to express the second condition. I'll write this in a way that is similar to what you had in mind, but remember - both implementations are equivalent:

```
(define (wordtranslator word liste)
  (cond ((null? liste) 'Error)
        ((not (or (equal? word (car (car liste)))
                  (equal? word (car (cdr (car liste))))))
         (wordtranslator word (cdr liste)))
        (else
         (cond ((equal? word (car (car liste)))
                (car (cdr (car liste))))
               ((equal? word (car (cdr (car liste))))
                (car (car liste)))))))
```

I recommend that you use the first implementation, the `else` part is already expressing what the complex second condition is doing in the second implementation, see how reordering the conditions can simplify the code. Either way the translation works on both directions:

```
(wordtranslator 'Hund *lex*)
=> 'dog
(wordtranslator 'dog *lex*)
=> 'Hund
(wordtranslator 'bunny *lex*)
=> 'Error
```

Comment: Really? care to comment before downvoting a correct answer?

Comment: but I wanted to try to end the request in the first line so that not every word goes through the full complex

Comment: @TheDevilofme what do you mean? this implementation ends the recursion as soon as the word is found, notice that the recursion only advances in the last condition, all the other conditions stop as soon as the word is found or the list is empty

Comment: normaly I use this function to translate a sentence word to word, so when I have a lot of words my method would cancel its action directly after looking for the equality thats the important thing for me

Comment: @TheDevilofme the implementation you posted didn't work to begin with. My solution is working, and it finishes quickly as soon as it finds the word, it's not doing any extra work. Try to really understand it, you'll see that it's doing _exactly_ what you're asking, and as efficiently as it can be done using lists. I just reordered the conditions to be more efficient, that's all!

Comment: But in your method you ask every element of lex if it is the word, i want that i only ask every element if it is not the word thats the point where our codes are different

Comment: @TheDevilofme I added a second implementation that looks more like what you intended to do, but again: both are equivalent, and the first one is recommended.

Comment: @TheDevilofme I'm sorry, but you're mistaken. Both codes are 100% equivalent, "my method" is just the same as yours, it's just that I'm reordering the conditions to be more efficient. In "your method" you are asking every element if it is _not_ the word, whereas in "my method" I'm asking every element if it _is_ the word - now you see? either way the same number of elements will have to be checked! but in "your method" you end up doing _more_ `equal?` comparisons, first to check if if the element is _not_ the one, and then to find _the one that it is_.

Comment: Ok thank you Oscar i now seeing your scnd script that youve did it in my way thank you and sorry for this bad questioning of me